# ES256 publickey.pem throws exception while importing in Keycloak in version 22

Tags: jwt, keycloak, rs256

ES256 algo curve P-256 public key import
keycloak throws an error. It works for all other algorithms i.e
RS256,HS256.

```
ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] 
(executor-thread-73) Uncaught server error: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.keycloak.common.util.PemException: 
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: encoded key spec not 
recognized: algorithm identifier 1.2.840.10045.2.1 in key not 
recognised
```

Used openSSL command for generating publikey.pem alg: ES256,
curv:P-256
Add ES256 Provider in keycloak realm key setting.